# Lebesgue integral of a function that is measurable, finite almost everywhere, and integrable on a set of finite measure

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $f$ be measurable, finite a.e, and Lebesgue integrable on $\mathbb{R}$ . Show that for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a measurable set $E$ (i.e $\mu(E) < \infty$) such that:

$\int_{E} |f| > \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f| - \epsilon$

**My attempt**

Suppose that for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists set of finite measure $E$ such that:

$\int_{E} |f| \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f| - \epsilon$

Then:

$ \int_{\mathbb{R}\setminus{E}} |f| \geq \epsilon$

Since $\epsilon > 0$ was arbitrary then we have:

$ \int_{\mathbb{R}\setminus{E}} |f| = \infty$

But $\mu(\mathbb{R}\setminus{E}) \geq \mu(\mathbb{R}) - \mu(E) = \infty$

This contradicts the fact that $g$ is finite a.e.

I don’t think my answer is correct because it seems pretty hand-wavy. Any thoughts on a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have assumed the result, which is not a valid proof.

Rather, given $\epsilon>0$, since $E_{n}=\{x\in{\bf{R}}:|x|\leq n,|f(x)|<n\}$ is such that $\chi_{E_{n}}|f|\uparrow|f|$ a.e. since $f$ is finite a.e., then Monotone Convergence Theorem gives 
\begin{align*}
\int\chi_{E_{n}}|f|\uparrow\int|f|,
\end{align*}
so there exists some $n_{0}$ such that 
\begin{align*}
\int\chi_{E_{n_{0}}}|f|>\int|f|-\epsilon.
\end{align*}
Note that 
\begin{align*}
\int\chi_{E_{n_{0}}}|f|=\int_{E_{n_{0}}}|f|,
\end{align*}
and $|E_{n_{0}}|\leq 2n_{0}<\infty$.

Comment: I made a typo in the answer I attempted. Does it make more sense now?

Comment: The negation of the statement is there exists some $\epsilon>0$ such that the negation holds, so it is not that $\epsilon>0$ being arbitrary that you can claim the integral is then $\infty$.

Comment: hm yes I realize the negation of the statement is what you are saying but I thought it would be okay since I was using contradiction not contrapositive. But now I see that it’s not correct. Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain the $\uparrow$ notation? Does it mean “converges & increases to”?

Comment: Yes, convergence and the sequence is monotone, so the limit is the supremum.

Comment: In your set $E_n$ why do we need $|x| \leq n$?

Comment: In fact, why do we need $|g(x)| < n$?

Comment: By $|x|\leq n$ in $E_{n}$ is to make sure that $E_{n}$ has finite measure.

Comment: By both $|f(x)|\leq n$ and $|x|\leq n$, then $f$ is integrable on $E_{n}$, the integral is finite, then $\displaystyle\int|f|-\int\chi_{E_{n}}|f|$ is defined.